# SharePoint Online and Yammer

Tags: sharepoint-online, yammer

I have several site collections in SharePoint online tenant and few hundred documents uploaded in them. When I go to Yammer and try to post and click on "SharePoint" icon, I am not able to get those documents in dialog box. However, when I click on "Recent" tab, I am able to see some recently uploaded documents on SharePoint. Otherwise only documents I can see is of "One Drive" and not SharePoint.

EDIT: Adding screenshot below. This is the first screen which I get when I click on "Select a file on SharePoint". These folders are from Onedrive. There is no option to enter SharePoint URL too. When I click on "Recent" from left bar, it shows document from SharePoint which is uploaded recently.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this issue correctly, this is by design and users are only able to attach documents to Yammer and  Planner only from the default 'Shared documents' library.  Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation nor anything on the Office 365 road map.

Comment: But in recent tab, i can see documents from custom document library too.

Comment: Recent tab is not based on a particular library but rather a collection of search results based on individual usage (it is using Graph API), most likely different results for different users.

Comment: Agreed. But that is why I am confused. If by design functionality consist of having to upload from Shared Documents only, in recent is should not be showing Documents from other libraries!